# How to assign one shortcut to a sucession of commands in Macro section of TeXStudio?

Tags: texstudio

To compile an Asymptote file to generate a pdf file, one has to take the following succession of commands into account:

pdfLaTex + Asymptote + pdfLaTeX

How can I assign a specific shortcut to this combination in the Macro section of TeXStudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Options` -> `Configure TeXstudio` -> `Build` -> `User Commands`
[image]

Then `Add` -> `Configure Icon` -> (opens window "Quick Build Command") -> Select the commands and arrange them

[image]

Result:

[image]

For copy+paste:

`LaTeX + Asymptote` = `txs:///pdflatex | txs:///asy | txs:///pdflatex`

To configure a shortcut for this go to `Shortcuts` -> `Menus` -> `Tools` -> `User` -> `<commandname>`:

[image]